# Phoenix Cookies decryption

Tags: cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework

Using phoenix-framework:
I'm trying to read a cookie in an authorization plug. It is a signed cookie, but I can't get it decrypted again. How do I get its value?

Router

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug SmiksAanvraagWeb.Plugs.Auth

  end
```

My auth-plug

```
  @moduledoc false
  def init(_opts) do
  end

  def call(conn, _) do
    IO.inspect conn.cookies["user"] # RESULT: SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAARhYWFhbgYA3I_DCncBYgANLwA.wUU0R4tdGDlFgS_o7GOEN7TqPjzLhmQNEJphJtXdEo8
```

Comment: Why you are reading it directly instead of using session mechanism?

Comment: Because my sessions are lost after the client submits an Ajax call.

Comment: Did you try with [`Phoenix.Token.verify/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html#verify/4) ?
`Phoenix.Token.verify(YourappWeb.Endpoint, app_secret, conn.cookies["user"])`

Comment: I got it working by manually decoding it like they explained here https://bitcrowd.dev/decoding-phoenix-session-cookies

Comment: As the author of that blog post, it brings me joy you found it helpful :) @KristofvanWoensel

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the discussion, but we solved by calling `fetch_cookies/2` with the `:signed` option, as written [here](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#fetch_cookies/2). For example: `fetch_cookies(conn, signed: ["my_cookie_name"])`.

Looking at the implementation [here](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/fb6b952cf93336dc79ec8d033e09a424d522ce56/lib/plug/conn.ex#L1354), `fetch_cookies/2` calls `verify_or_decrypt/4`, which puts the verified value on `conn.cookies` instead.

This way we let `fetch_cookies/2` handle the verification and decoding of the cookie, instead of having to do manually.

The same applies for encrypted cookies too, using the `:encrypted` option instead of the `:signed` option.

Comment: This worked great for me - just noting that if I do `conn = fetch_cookies(conn, signed: ["my_auth_cookie"])` and then `get_session(conn, :my_session_token)` I can get the information from the session itself.